# Is it legit to put the style declaration inside the body?

Tags: css, html

Is it legit to put the style declaration inside the body tag? Another way to put it is, is there any reason not to put it inside the body tag if I need to?

Before:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #Ellipse_1{stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:8px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg style="position:absolute;width:121px;height:121px;">
        <ellipse id="Ellipse_1" rx="60.5" ry="60.5" cx="147.5" cy="164.5">
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

After:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    #Ellipse_1{stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:8px;}
  </style>
  <svg style="position:absolute;width:121px;height:121px;">
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_1" rx="60.5" ry="60.5" cx="147.5" cy="164.5">
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML is a fickle religion. I've had arguments about putting style inside the html, and I've been on both sides of the argument over the years. It seems the fashion is again turning to 'Yes, go ahead' but remember that you'd be burnt as a witch if you asked the same question 6 months ago, sooo… do what you like, and have a reason for doing it :)

Comment: In this case you could put it simply in the svg tag, too

Comment: HTML, unless you're in STRICT mode is so passive. You can do so many errors in a document, it'll force itself to go on and on. Yes. You can put it anywhere, but it is better to put it in <head>, so the style loads BEFORE the content.